# I keep getting this message when I compile: The constructor BabysittingJob(int, int, int, int, int) is undefined

Tags: java

I keep getting this message when I compile: The constructor `BabysittingJob(int, int, int, int, int)` is undefined. I am trying to create a babysitting application. The question is quite lenghty but i hope the information I have provided is sufficient. All the code works except for the point where I have to construct a BaysittingJob object and display its values. Thank you so much.

I cannot get the application to output the dsired results. It is supposed to:
1. Display a job number with two digits of the year and a four digit sequential number
2. The assined babysitter based on the baby sitter code selected (code is from 1 to 3)
3. The number of children
4. The number of hours worked
5. A fee based on the number of hours worked and the babysitter selected
    If babysitter code is 1, $7 per hour fee is charged
    If babysitter code is 2 or 3, fee is $9 per hour for the first child and $4 per additional hour for each additional child

```
  public class BabysittingJob
{
private int jobNumber;
private int babysitterCode;
private String babysitter;
private int childrenNumber;
private int hoursWorked;
private double fee; 

public BabysittingJob (int year, int sequentialNumber, int babysitterCode, int childrenNumber, int hoursWorked, String babysitter)
{
year = year % 2000;
int jobNumber = ((year*10000) + sequentialNumber); 
if (babysitterCode == 1)
 babysitter = "Cindy";
else if(babysitterCode ==2)
 babysitter = "Greg";
else if(babysitterCode ==3)
 babysitter = "Marcia";
}
{

if(babysitterCode == 1)
 fee = hoursWorked * 7 * childrenNumber;
else if (babysitterCode > 1 && childrenNumber ==1)
 fee = hoursWorked * 9 * childrenNumber;
else if (babysitterCode >1 && childrenNumber > 1)
 fee = (hoursWorked * 9) + ((--childrenNumber) * hoursWorked * 4);
}
public void displayResult()
{
  System.out.println("Your job number is:" + jobNumber + "Your baby sitter is:" + babysitter + 
                     "The number of children is:" + childrenNumber + "The number of hours worked is:"
                    + hoursWorked + "Your fee is $:" + fee);
}
}


    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class CreateBabysittingJob
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter year.");
    int year = input.nextInt();
    while (year < 2013 || year > 2025)
    {
    System.out.println("Enter a year between 2013 and 2025");
    year = input.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.print("Enter job number");
    int jobNumber = input.nextInt();
    while (jobNumber < 1 || jobNumber > 9999)
    {
    System.out.println ("Enter a number between 1 and 9999");
    jobNumber = input.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.print("Enter babysitter code");
    int babysitterCode = input.nextInt();
    while (babysitterCode < 1 || babysitterCode > 3)
    {
    System.out.println ("Enter a number between 1 and 3");
    babysitterCode = input.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.print ("Enter number of children"); 
    int childrenNumber = input.nextInt();
    while(childrenNumber < 1 || childrenNumber > 9)
    {
    System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 9");
    childrenNumber = input.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.print("Enter number of hours");
    int hoursWorked = input.nextInt();
    while( hoursWorked < 1 || hoursWorked > 12)
    {
    System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 12");
    hoursWorked = input.nextInt();
    }
    BabysittingJob ca = new BabysittingJob(year, jobNumber, babysitterCode, childrenNumber, hoursWorked);
    ca.displayResult();
    }
    }
```

Comment: really, you put so much effort into that question I can't help but putting the same amount in to answering it ...

Comment: I have formatted the code for you. Please read the help links on this site to see how to do this for your next question here.

Comment: Aaagggghhh my eyes! They buuuuurn

Comment: No constructor for CreateBabysittingJob class

Comment: I disagree. All the necessary effort is in this question to answer it for yourself! You've stated the problem. Now is there a constructor `BabysittingJob(...)`

Comment: sorry I tried to shorten the question because it is quite lengthy. Will posting the first part of the code help?

Comment: @FalabiAdebola: you have to give us necessary information so that we can answer your question. If your compiler is complaining that a class doesn't have a constructor, it kind of makes sense that you should show that class, right?

Answer (score 1):

Your BabysittingJob constructor accepts int, int, int, int, int, String:

```
 public BabysittingJob (int year, int sequentialNumber, int babysitterCode, 
     int childrenNumber, int hoursWorked, String babysitter)  {
```

You're trying to call it with int, int, int, int, but you are not passing in the String:

```
BabysittingJob ca = new BabysittingJob(year, jobNumber, babysitterCode, 
     childrenNumber, hoursWorked);
```

Solution: either pass in the final String parameter when calling the constructor, or create a new constructor that doesn't require the final String parameter.

Comment: i have some new questions regarding the same application. I edited m previous post. I am starting to get a hang of things. Thanks

Comment: @FalabiAdebola: then start a new question on stackoverflow. Don't extend your existing question.